# How to merge 2d array into string in python

Tags: python, join, list-comprehension

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103844/how-do-i-merge-a-2d-array-in-python-into-one-string-with-list-comprehension) but the problem I am facing is that when I want to convert

```
[[65, 'D', 'M', 'A', 'H'], [65, 'S', 'I', 'N']]
```

to string using the method above , what i get is

```
'65DMAH65SIN'
```

but what I want is

```
'65DMAH 65SIN'
```

i.e after every array ends, it gives me space. I am thinking of logics for this but not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use following comprehension for that task:

```
a = [[65, 'D', 'M', 'A', 'H'], [65, 'S', 'I', 'N']]
s = ' '.join(''.join(map(str,i)) for i in a)
print(s)
```

Output:

```
65DMAH 65SIN
```

For every sublist I map it, so every element of sublist become str, then I join elements of every sublist without separator (empty str), which then I join using space.

Answer (score 0):

> Your problem answer is:

```
def solution(List):
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in string[i]:
            result+=str(j)
        result+=' '
    return result
```